# [...next].js error "'session.user' is possibly 'undefined'." but I'm able to access the value of session.user.name

Tags: next.js, next-auth

error is showing this --->'session.user' is possibly 'undefined'.
but i can access the value session.user.name but why this error i'm unable to execute npm run build now

Header.tsx

```
          const { data: session } = useSession()

          ...

          <div 
              onClick={() => {!session? signIn(): signOut()}}
              className='items-center justify-center px-2 text- 
              white cursor-pointer hover:ring-1 hover:ring-white '>
               <p className='font-normal '>{!session ?   "sign in" 
               : `Hello ${session.user.name}`}</p>
                                 ^^^^^
               <h3 className='-mt-1 font-bold'>Account & Lists</h3>
            </div>
```

[...next].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    // OAuth authentication providers...
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    })
  ]
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Comment: Have you tried session?.user?.name

Answer (score 2):

just do this :   {session?.user?.name}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

{session && session.user ? `Hello ${session.user.name}`: "sign in"}

I solve this problem, here I just need to check if the session and session.user are also true

Answer (score 0):

```
const { data: session } = useSession()
const user = session ? session.user : null ;
    
    return (
          <div 
              onClick={() => {!user? signIn(): signOut()}}
              className='items-center justify-center px-2 text- 
              white cursor-pointer hover:ring-1 hover:ring-white '>
               <p className='font-normal '>{!user ?   "sign in" 
               : `Hello ${user.name}`}</p>
                                 ^^^^^
               <h3 className='-mt-1 font-bold'>Account & Lists</h3>
            </div>
    )
```

Comment: not gonna work because I don't want to check if the session is true or not, I want to access the value of session.user.name, I can access the value in the UI it shows my google account name but gets this error in the code that prevents my build command

session.user' is possibly 'undefined'

Comment: @SOOVIKKUNDU I just updated my answer. I just copied code from my working website. It should work.